# Flux through a hemisphere

Tags: vector-analysis, surfaces, surface-integrals

I need to calculate the flux through a Hemisphere given implicitly:

$M = \{(X,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1, z \geq 0\}$

Or as I parametrised in Polar coordinates:

$\psi(\varphi, \theta) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos(\varphi)\,\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\varphi)\,\sin(\theta)\\ \cos(\theta)\end{array}\right), \quad \varphi \in[0,2\,\pi] \quad \theta\in[0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}] $

Through the Vector Field: $F = \begin{array}{c}(x^2\,y \quad  y^2\,z \quad z^2\,x)\end{array}$

Of course I know flux can be calculated by:

$\Phi = \int_M \langle F, N\rangle\,\mathrm{dA}$ Where $N$ is the unit normal field of the sphere:

$N = \left(\begin{array}{c}-\cos(\varphi)\,\sin(\theta) \\ -\sin(\varphi)\,\sin(\theta) \\ -\cos(\theta)\end{array}\right)$

also $F$ is a composition: $F \circ \psi(\varphi,\theta)$:

$F = \left(\begin{array}{c}\cos^2(\varphi)\,\sin^3(\theta)\,\sin(\varphi) \\ \sin^2(\varphi) \, \sin^2(\theta) \,\cos(\theta) \\ \cos^2(\theta)\,\cos(\varphi)\,\sin(\varphi)\end{array}\right)$

So all gathered together:

$\begin{align}&\Phi = \displaystyle{\int_0^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^{2\,\pi} \bigg\langle \left(\begin{array}{c}\cos^2(\varphi)\,\sin^3(\theta)\,\sin(\varphi) \\ \sin^2(\varphi) \, \sin^2(\theta) \,\cos(\theta) \\ \cos^2(\theta)\,\cos(\varphi)\,\sin(\varphi)\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{c}-\cos(\varphi)\,\sin(\theta) \\ -\sin(\varphi)\,\sin(\theta) \\ -\cos(\theta)\end{array}\right)\bigg\rangle\,\mathrm{d\varphi\,d\theta}}\\ \\ 
&\Phi = \displaystyle{\int_0^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^{2\,\pi}-\cos^3(\varphi)\,\sin^4(\theta)\,\sin(\varphi)\,\cos(\varphi)-\sin^3(\varphi)\,\sin^3(\theta)\,\cos(\theta)-\cos^3(\theta)\,\cos(\varphi)\,\sin(\varphi)\,\mathrm{d\varphi\,d\theta}}\end{align}$

What results into an integral that seems pretty hard to deal with. Here I'm hanging

Comment: Two comments: I would continue with what you have, that integral can be computed with usual techniques (unless I'm mistaken); you could also apply divergence theorem to make the computation easier, but that would require that you've heard of it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistakes in your working. Check the normal vector. Also the z component of $\vec F(\psi(\varphi, \theta))$ has a mistake.

First, a quick check: $ \ \vec F = (x^2y, y^2z, z^2x)$ and unit normal vector to the sphere is $\hat n = (x, y, z)$. So integral of $\vec F \cdot \hat n = x^3y + y^3z + z^3x$ over surface $S: x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1, z \geq 0$ will be zero due to symmetry about xz and yz planes.

Coming back to your working, if you have parametrized the surface as,

$\psi(\varphi, \theta) = (\cos\varphi\sin\theta,  \sin\varphi\sin\theta , \cos\theta), \quad \varphi \in[0,2\,\pi] \quad \theta\in\left[0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$

Then outward normal vector $\vec N = \psi_\theta \times \psi_\varphi = (\sin^2\theta \cos\varphi, \sin^2\theta \sin\varphi, \sin\theta \cos\theta)$

$\vec F = \left(\cos^2\varphi\sin\varphi\sin^3\theta, \sin^2\varphi  \sin^2\theta\cos\theta, \cos\varphi\cos^2\theta\sin\theta\right)$

So, flux through the surface is,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2\pi} \vec F \cdot \vec N \ d\varphi \ d\theta$

$= \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2\pi} \left(\cos^3\varphi\sin\varphi\sin^5\theta + \sin^3\varphi  \sin^4\theta\cos\theta + \cos\varphi\cos^3\theta\sin^2\theta\right) \ d\varphi \ d\theta$

The inner integral is zero and hence the flux is zero.

Comment: Thank you for the effort retracing my calculations. Using the symmmertrie will clearly reduce the effort, but I don't quite grasp why the integral will be zero? is it because of the reverse-$2\,pi$-periodicity of $\cos, \sin$? Also I've been asked using the the Unit Normal Vector. But doesn't really matter since those are similar. Additionally as you told me in a previous question it's even redundant normalising or not.

Comment: To the first part of your question, yes it is due to periodicity of sin and cos functions. Take sin function for example, it is positive in first and second quadrant and negative in third and fourth quadrant. So the integral over first and second quadrant will cancel out integral over third and fourth quadrant. In surface integrals, always look for presence of odd functions and check for symmetry to simplify your working.

Comment: For the second part of your question, there is no need to normalize but if you do, you must note in that case that $dS = R^2 \sin \theta \ d\varphi \ d\theta$. Here $R = 1$.

Comment: Right, Thanks for recalling $\mathrm{dS} = \vert \vec{n} \vert \,\mathrm{d \varphi\,d\theta}$. Our Tutor was really holding this back.